# What is the safest way, to allow non authenticated users to interact with Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am currently working on an app, where user creates a group of people, and sends them links to take a part in a draw.

The draw mechanism includes reading and writing inside group array inside firestore database.

```
users/uid/groups/groupid
```

Link has groupid and personName inside a url that looks like this.

https://website.com/draw?groupId=Firma%20Birma9799bb92-e1ee-414b-a668-9eccc600b7d0&personName=Diambus%20Parambus

This enables fetch mechanism to know which data inside firestore database to target and for who, the problem is that for it to work link would also need some form of authentication, so that the fetching mechanism works and can get through users/uid part

that's because security rules that I implement only allow users with the same uid as the folder, to access it.

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
```

I was thinking about encoding uid into the link then decoding it some way in firestore with a cloud function, or using some sort of token-based access that only works once.